AMF custom properties validations

I am implementing custom rulesets using [AMF][1], I could not find the sufficient documentation to continue this.
Goal: I am trying to validate if the custom properties exists or not and if they exists I want to verify against some Regex pattern.
Below is the OAS for positive test:
openapi: "3.0.0"
info:
  x-audience: foo
  x-api-id: bar
  title: example API
  version: "1.0.0"
paths: {} 

Custom Properties

x-api-id
x-audience

So far I have created a rule that can check if they exist or not, but I additionally need pattern validation so that it can validate the value of the property too (like foo, bar). It does not give correct result if I use pattern: after  exactCount:.
#%Validation Profile 1.0
profile: "api-identifier-215"
warning:
  - api-identifier-215

validations:
  api-identifier-215:  
    message: test message
    targetClass: apiContract.WebAPI
    propertyConstraints:
      apiExt.api-id:
        exactCount: 1
      


Thank you in advance.
